# Hide undefined for item.message

Tags: jquery, append, hide, undefined

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/BogdanErimia/posts/?access_token=xxxxx&date_format=U&limit=17&callback=?', function(feed) {
    $.each(feed.data, function(index, item){
        $('.tweet').append('<div class="item-normal"><div class="normal"><div id="story2">' + item.message + '</div></div><div class="twitterbg"></div></div>');
        if ( index == 10 ) return false;
    });
});
```

There are some items in the feed without this "message", and for them give me "undefined" error. I want to hide it please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `if(item.message)` before you append a row.  You may want to use a counter now, to check when you hit the 10th row.

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/BogdanErimia/posts/?access_token=xxxxx&date_format=U&limit=17&callback=?', function(feed) {
    var counter = 0;
    $.each(feed.data, function(index, item){
        if(item.message){
           $('.tweet').append('<div class="item-normal"><div class="normal"><div id="story2">' + item.message + '</div></div><div class="twitterbg"></div></div>');
           counter++;
        }
        if ( counter === 10 ) return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: but what if i want an other item.etc that has the same problem ? i want them to work together.. something like if(item.message, item.caption), or i don't know

Comment: You can try `if(item.message || item.caption)`

Comment: no... didn't worked.... it give me just 1 feed from caption... or maybe the append is the problem " + urllinks(item.message) + urllinks(item.caption) + "

Comment: When concating the strings, try using `(item.message || '')`, this will use a blank string, if the message is `undefined`. `+ urllinks(item.message || '') + urllinks(item.caption || '') +`

Comment: the first one is the message, but all the rest are caption

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/BogdanErimia/posts/?access_token=xxxxx&date_format=U&limit=17&callback=?', function(feed) {
    $.each(feed.data, function(index, item){
        if (item.message) {
           $('.tweet').append('<div class="item-normal"><div class="normal"><div id="story2">' + item.message + '</div></div><div class="twitterbg"></div></div>');
        }
        if ( index == 10 ) return false;
    });
});
```